# definir variables en funcion de condicion

Tags: java

queria definir una serie de variables para realizar la conexion con una base de datos u otra en funcion de si es verdadera una variable. Pero me salen errores de compilacion. Os muestro el codigo:

```
public class tiendaSuvenirs extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static final boolean PrestaShop=false;
static final boolean Wordpress=true;

if(PrestaShop)
{
public static String nombreBd="nombre";
public static String userBd="usuario";
public static String passwordBd="contraseña";
}
if(WordPress)
{
public static String nombreBd="nombre";
public static String userBd="usuario";
public static String passwordBd="contraseña";
}
...
```

¿seria posible hacer esto?
un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Atendiendo al código que pones prueba lo siguiente:

```
static boolean PrestaShop = false;
static boolean Wordpress = true;
static String nombreBd = "";
static String userBd = "";
static String passwordBd = "";

if(PrestaShop)
{
   nombreBd = "nombre";
   userBd = "usuario";
   passwordBd = "contraseña";
}

if(WordPress)
{
   nombreBd = "nombre";
   userBd = "usuario";
   passwordBd = "contraseña";
}
```

Declaras tus **variables nombreBd**, **userBd** y **passwordBd** afuera de los **bloques if** de esta forma puedes usar estas variables dentro del método donde son declaradas, como tú lo tenías solamente podías usarlas dentro de los **bloque if**. Una vez hecho esto pues preguntarías tal como ya haces por las **variables PrestaShop** y **WordPress** y atendiendo a si se cumplen o no estas condiciones llenarías las **variables nombreBd**, **userBd** y **passwordBd** con los valores correspondientes.

Comment: me da un error de compilacion en el if: illegal start of type

Comment: @guillanBesada revisa bien lo nuevo q puse, no es cortar y pegar mi codigo y ya, se trata de analizar tambien, le quite los final a las variables booleanas

Comment: si, lo he puesto tal y como tienes tu, pero me da este error, lo puedes ver en esta captura de pantalla en el siguiente link: https://postimg.cc/5Xvd2tFX

Comment: quiza es porque estan encima de todo de la clase y ahi igual no se permiten bolques if

Comment: @guillanBesada, pero por supuesto q debe ser eso, los if deben estar dentro de metodos que esta dentro de una clase, la clase es la que agrupa todo eso, tu eres principiante verdad?